# $10$ Equations in $10$ variables

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

Define,

$$F_k = xp^k + yq^k + zr^k + us^k + vt^k$$

Let,

$$F_0 = 2$$

$$F_1 = 3$$

$$F_2  = 16$$

$$F_3 = 31$$

$$F_4 = 103$$

$$F_5 = 235$$

$$F_6 = 674$$

$$F_7 = \color{blue}{1667}$$

$$F_8 = 4526$$

$$F_9 = 11595$$

Solve for $x, y, z, u, v, p, q, r, s, t$

Can anyone post a solution if you have solved it? Thanks.

$\color{blue}{Edit}$:

It seems there is a typo. Compare to OEIS [A072684](https://oeis.org/A072684):

$$2, 3, 16, 31, 103, 235, 674, \color{blue}{1669}, 4526, 11595,\dots$$

Comment: It seems there is only a numerical solution.

Comment: Are we over the complex numbers ? Over the integers ? Over a finite field ?

Comment: Well... I think the real solutions (if any) should be found out. Yes. On a finite field.

Comment: @user232216 I guess you mean "finite number". Finite field is a totally different thing.

Comment: It is possible to rewrite the system only on variables $p,q,r,s,t$ by applying the inverse of Vandermonde's matrices. However, the system becomes so complicated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is *way* too localized.  If this question is a suitable fit for the site, what is to prevent me from making up some other nonlinear system of $n$ variables with $n$ equations and asking that one?  Unless this can be answered with a suitable method for solving such systems, I fail to see how solving *this one problem* will be of help to future visitors.

Comment: @apnorton I disagree this question is too localized. This type of equations is easily realizable in nature. Consider you have a quantum system in mixed state and what you know is the expected energy at different temperature. To backout the underlying energy level and weight, you essentially need to solve a system of non-linear equations of this particular form. In certain sense, this problem is very generic, it is a problem of model calibration using observed moments.

Comment: @achillehui Fair enough.  Vote retracted.

Comment: @apnorton: I think the OP made a typo. I believe he was using a [sequence](https://oeis.org/A072684) studied by Ramanujan. See my comment to achillehui's answer.

Answer (score 6):

Up to permutation of following $5$ pairs of parameters,
We have
$$\begin{array}{ccrrr}
(x,p) &\approx& (&1.224327053331513,&-1.63524424694438),\\
(y,q) &\approx& (&-0.4394128984751902,&-1.057614953906837),\\
(z,r) &\approx& (&-1.053916434658547,& 1.095032163962836),\\
(u,s) &\approx& (&0.2923729654397071,&1.726036072413793),\\
(v,t) &\approx& (&1.976629314362518,&2.624048014170645)
\end{array}$$

and $(p,q,r,s,t)$ are roots of the polynomial

$${\lambda}^{5}-\frac{167973}{61031}\lambda^4-\frac{222201}{61031}\lambda^3 +\frac{649807}{61031}\lambda^2 + \frac{165745}{61031}\lambda - 
\frac{523491}{61031} = 0$$

The coefficients
$$(\alpha_0,\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3,\alpha_4) = \left( \frac{523491}{61031},-\frac{165745}{61031},-\frac{649807}{61031},\frac{222201}{61031},\frac{167973}{61031} \right)$$
are solution for following matrix equation

$$\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 3 & 16 & 31 & 103\\
3 & 16 & 31 & 103 & 235\\
16 & 31 & 103 & 235 & 674\\
31 & 103 & 235 & 674 & 1667\\
103 & 235 & 674 & 1667 & 4526
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha_0\\
\alpha_1\\
\alpha_2\\
\alpha_3\\
\alpha_4
\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}
235\\
674\\
1667\\
4526\\
11595
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{*1}
$$

The basic idea goes like this. 
Instead of solving $p,q,r,s,t$, we look at following polynomial first:

$$(\lambda -p)(\lambda - q)(\lambda - r)(\lambda - s)(\lambda - t)
= \lambda^5 - (\alpha_4 \lambda^4 + \alpha_3\lambda^3 + \alpha_2\lambda^2 + \alpha_1\lambda + \alpha_0)$$

It is easy to see the list of power sums

$$u_k = x p^k + y q^k + z r^k + u s^k + v t^k$$

satisfies a recurrence relation of the form:

$$u_{n+5} = \alpha_4 u_{n+4} + \alpha_3 u_{n+3} + \alpha_2 u_{n+2} + \alpha_1 u_{n+1} + \alpha_0 u_{n}$$

This means one can backout the parameters $\alpha_0,\ldots,\alpha_4$ using the supplied power sums. This is the rationale behind equation $(*1)$.

Once we have $\alpha_0, \ldots, \alpha_4$,  we can use whatever means
to locate the roots of the quintic polynomial. The roots of the quintic
polynomial will be our variables $(p, q, r, s, t)$.

After we obtain $(p,q,r,s,t)$, it is trivial to setup linear equations to
compute the corresponding $(x,y,z,u,v)$. I will skip the details here.

Comment: I missed the relation between the coefficients $\alpha$ and the variables $p,q,r,s,t$. Could you explain the details?

Comment: @AlexSilva answer updated, I hope the rationale is clear now.

Comment: Now, it is very clear! Very nice answer! :)

Comment: @achillehui: I think the OP used an OEIS sequence, but made a typo. (It should be $\color{blue}{1669}$, not $1667$.) With this assumption, the quintic coefficients are _much_ simpler being single digits as $$a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4 = 1,\,-3,\,-1,\,5,\,1$$

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is closed form solution in $\mathbb R$. I fed the equation into Mathematica and the solution involves some simultaneous quintic equations.

The numerical solution is:

```
p =  1.0950321639628354969
q = -1.0576149539068368954
r = -1.6352442469443802722
s =  2.6240480141706460457
t =  1.7260360724137917277

x = -1.0539164346585613344
y = -0.43941289847517655928
z =  1.2243270533315074403
u =  1.9766293143625121080
v =  0.29237296543971834535
```

Comment: Are there other numerical solutions ?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Mathematica gives 120 solutions, but, you know, $5!=120$. So this is the only solution modulo symmetry.

Comment: @kennytm: Apparently the OP made a crucial typo. See my edit to his post.