# System of $n+1$ polynomial equations in $2m$ unknowns

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system, real-algebraic-geometry

I aim to study the following system of equations with respect to $(x_{1}, \dots, x_{m}, y_{1}, \dots, y_{m})$

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
y_1x_1+y_2x_2+y_3x_3 + \dots + y_mx_m=c_1 \\ 
y_1x_1^2+y_2x_2^2+y_3x_3^2 + \dots + y_mx_m^2=c_2\\ 
y_1x_1^3+y_2x_2^3+y_3x_3^3 + \dots + y_mx_m^3=c_3\\
\vdots\\
y_1x_1^n+y_2x_2^n+y_3x_3^n + \dots + y_mx_m^n=c_n\\
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

with the constraint $y_{1} + y_{2} + \dots + y_{m} = 1$. We assume that $n=2m-1$.

Is there any way to solve it? I do not know how to start.

Comment: What relation, if any, is there between $n$ and $m$?

Comment: Dear @saulspatz, I have edited.

Comment: I think it may have something to do with the [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix)   Think of the $x\text{'}$s as the elements of the matrix and the $y\text{'}$s as a vector so that we have $YX=C$

Comment: yes, it will be Vandermonde. The thing is that X is also a variable.

Comment: Look at my answer to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1238939/10-equations-in-10-variables/1238993), which is a special case of this for $m = 5$. The methodology can be generalized to your case.

Comment: Dear @achille hui, thank you. I see. Just would like to clarify, if we need the conditions on the values of $c_{i}$ (or F_{i}) in that example?

Comment: Yes, the sequence $c_i$ satisfy a recurrence relation, once you figure out the coefficients for the recurrence relation, the $x_1, \ldots, x_m$ will be the root for corresponding polynomial.

Comment: dear  achille hui. Which conditions do we need for the existence of the solution? It is really not clear for me...